# Google captcha work on local but not work on server?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I tested it on local and worked fine, then I uploaded it and created new google captcha and it does not work.

here is my code :

+view

```
<form action="/register" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="<?=$csrf['name'];?>" value="<?=$csrf['hash'];?>" />
    <div class="g-recaptcha set-captcha" data-sitekey="6LfiTykUAAAAAN6-98TDoIVHNMVedR6jtKAEXa6S"></div>
<button type="submit" class="button userlogin">Apply</button>
```

+controller:

```
public function _submit_register(&$data){

$form_response = $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response');
$url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$sitekey = "6LfiTykUAAAAAOYfu_NGbeUHuq_dZxO5_n0oynMO";
$response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$sitekey."&response=".$form_response."&remoteip=".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
$data_cap = json_decode($response);

if(isset($data_cap->success) && $data_cap->success=="true")
    {
        $insert_id = $this->mo_user->insert($dealer_data);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Please fill captcha')</script>";
    }
}
```

please help me to fix this issue !!!

thank you for your help !!!

Comment: Google captcha requires you to set domains where it works.

Comment: yeah, I create it ready. but I don't know it still not work ?

Comment: If you press F12 in Chrome or any other web browser, you should probably see some error messages. What do you see?

Comment: on this when I test on local it work, but I upload it to server it also alert me "Please fill captcha" I don't know why ?

Comment: What is in `/register` method?

Comment: Are the PHP versions the same? Is there any console errors? How does it not work when you upload it to the server?

Comment: /register is route of class  _submit_register